# In a Kendo Grid, how I do disable dragging while doing an inline edit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I've got a kendo grid with a draggable attached to it to allow reordering of grid rows.

```
        grid.table.kendoDraggable({
            filter: "tbody > tr",
            group: "gridGroup",
            hint: function (e) {
                return $('<div class="k-grid k-widget"><table><tbody><tr>' + e.html() + '</tr></tbody></table></div>');
            }
        });

        grid.table.kendoDropTarget({
            group: "gridGroup",
            drop: function (e) {
                e.draggable.hint.hide();
                var target = dataSource.getByUid($(e.draggable.currentTarget).data("uid")),
                    dest = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));

                if (dest.is("th")) {
                    return;
                }

                dest = dataSource.getByUid(dest.parent().data("uid"));

                if (target.get("Id") !== dest.get("Id")) {
                    var tmp = target.Priority;
                    target.Priority = dest.Priority;
                    dest.Priority = tmp;

                    dataSource.sort({ field: "Priority", dir: "asc" });
                }
            }
        });
```

I also have the ability to do inline edits by setting

```
editable: "inline"
```

and

```
{
    command: ["edit"]
}
```

However, Kendo grid does some screwing things when dragging is enabled while trying to click on an editable field. When I comment out the kendoDraggable code, editing works just fine. I'm looking for a way of capturing the kendoGrid "edit" command and using that to disable the draggability. Of course, I'd need to re-enable dragging after the user leaves inline editing mode.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

You can just make the filter to exclude a row which is being currently edited.

```
grid.table.kendoDraggable({
  filter: "tbody > tr:not(.k-grid-edit-row)",
```

[Here is live example](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/487/edit).